# Uniqueness of the Chern character

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, vector-bundles

The Chern character of the vector bundle may be defined in means of characteristic classes or using differential geometric quantities. It can be shown that it satisfies the conditions $$ch(f^*E)=f^*ch(E)$$
$$ch(E \oplus F)=ch(E)+ch(F)$$ 
$$ch(E \otimes F)=ch(E) \cup ch(F).$$
Can anybody give me reference for the proof that these properties characterise Chern character uniquely?

Comment: You need a non-degeneracy condition, otherwise you can take the zero map $\operatorname{Vect}(X) \to H^*(X; \mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: These conditions imply, via the splitting principle, that the Chern character is determined by the Chern character of the tautological line bundle on $\mathbb{CP}^{\infty}$. Then you need one more condition fixing what this is (or else you could equally well take the "opposite" Chern character given by taking the Chern character of the conjugate vector bundle).